# Handling higher read load by adding read replicas to Aurora DB

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, scaling, amazon-aurora

Our system is experiencing a higher load which is causing the database CPU to increase and also the queue depth to increase as traffic increases to the system.

This system is a practically a read database which we sync daily. Would adding read replicas to this system help scaling up the database and handling the increased read load? As I understand it, Aurora automatically distributes the load right?

We are using an Aurora Postgres instance that is db.t3.medium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would adding read replicas to this system help scaling up the database
> and handling the increased read load?

If the database CPU is truly your bottleneck, then yes adding a read replica and distributing some of your reads to it should help.

> As I understand it, Aurora automatically distributes the load right?

Not really. It provides a DNS-Load-Balanced read-only endpoint. As long as you configure your database connections to use that endpoint for read-only queries, then they should be fairly distributed.